# python unit test with mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

Following is the pseudo code I was about to do a python unit test:

```
def my_method():
    run asynchronous_job, which will write to output_file when it's done
    while True:
        if output_file was written (by asynchronous_job):
            break
        else:
            sleep one second
```

I was trying to get `asynchronous_job` mocked up, but then I don't know how to test the `while` loop behavior because `output_file` will never been written with `asynchronous_job` mocked. What is the best way to do the unit test for `my_method` regarding this issue?

Comment: Your title says you are using mocker, but your tags suggest you are using `unittest.mock` from the Python 3 stdlib (backported as `mock`). Which one is it?

Comment: Tag modified. Thanks!